# Parse comment block with keyword sections

Tags: python, pyparsing

Try to parse procedure documentation comment block with pyparsing.

```
proc test {a b c} {
    # Proc description
    # :args: a - argument a, b - second argument
    #        c - third argument
    # :return: nothing

    puts $a
}
```

Tokens below created:

```py
EOL = Suppress(pp.LineEnd())
line = pp.SkipTo(EOL)
commentStart = pp.Suppress('#')
commentLine = tclCommentStart + restOfLine

startDocsReturn = commentStart + pp.Keyword(":return:").suppress()
docsReturnLine = startDocsReturn + line
startDocsArgs = commentStart + pp.Keyword(":args:").suppress()
docsArgsLine = startDocsArgs + line
docsDescription = pp.OneOrMore(commentLine, stopOn=startDocsArgs).setParseAction(join_lines)
```

But it parse correctly if args block is one line. If it is multiline then adding OneOrMore to line token in docsArgsLine doesn't work because the line starts from the sharp character.

What is the correct expression to parse keyword multiline block whish start from special characters?